# How we obtain explicitly the long exact sequence of the exponential exact sequence?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory

Good evening everyone,
The exponential exact sequence is defined by: 
$ 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to^{i} \mathcal{O} \to^{g} \mathcal{O}^{*} \to 0 $
with : $ g(f) = e^{ 2 \pi i f } $ and $ i $ is the sheaf embedding map.
Could you explain me please, how we define its exact long exact sequence:
$$ 0 \to H^0 ( X , \mathbb{Z} ) \to^{i_{0}} H^0 ( X , \mathcal{O} ) \to^{g_{0}} H^0 ( X , \mathcal{O}^{*} ) \to^{c_{0}} H^1 ( X , \mathbb{Z} ) \\
\to^{i_{1}} H^1 ( X , \mathcal{O} ) \to^{g_{1}} H^1 ( X , \mathcal{O}^{*} ) \to^{c_{1}} H^2 ( X , \mathbb{Z} ) \\
\to^{i_{2}} H^2 ( X , \mathcal{O} ) \to^{g_{2}} H^2 ( X , \mathcal{O}^{*} ) \to^{c_{2}} H^3 ( X , \mathbb{Z} ) \\
\to^{i_{3}} H^3 ( X , \mathcal{O} ) \to^{g_{3}} H^3 ( X , \mathcal{O}^{*} ) \to^{c_{3}} H^4 ( X , \mathbb{Z} )$$

I mean,  how are defined explicitly : $H^{k-1} ( X , \mathcal{O}^* ) \to^{c_{k-1}} H^k ( X , \mathbb{Z} )$ and $H^k ( X , \mathbb{Z} ) \to^{i_{k}} H^k ( X , \mathcal{O} )$ and $ H^k ( X , \mathcal{O} ) \to^{g_{k}} H^k ( X , \mathcal{O}^{*} ) $ with : $ k \geq 0 $ and how do we obtain them explicitly ?.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm assuming that saying "take a Čech cover" isn't good enough.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't understand that clearly, i'm just beginner in the field. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This Long exact sequence arises from the [Snake lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma).
Other [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SnakeLemma.html).

You obtain the long exact sequence from the short exact sequence by constructing connecting homomorphisms.

Comment: It seems to me that Bryan might not know what the complex in question is.

Comment: I think the question is not about how to prove existence of the connecting maps, but how to describe them explicitly.